# ManyToMany with and whereIn

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a ManyToMany relationship between AdInterest and AdInterestGroup models, with a belongsToMany() method in each model so I can use dynamic properties:

```
AdInterest->groups  
AdInterestGroup->interests
```

I can find all the "interests" in a single group like this:

```
$interests = AdInterestGroup::find(1)->interests->pluck('foo');
```

**What I need is a merged, deduplicated array of the related 'foo' field from multiple groups.**
I imagine I can deduplicate with `->unique()`, but first, as you'd expect, this:

```
AdInterestGroup::whereIn('id',[1,2])->interests->get();
```

throws:

> Property [interests] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.

The advice seems to be to use **eager loading** via *with()*:

```
AdInterestGroup::with('interests')->whereIn('id',[1,2])->get();
```

Firstly, as you'd expect that's giving me an array of two values though (one for each ID).

Also, if I try and `pluck('foo')` again, it's looking in the wrong database table: from the *AdInterestGroup* table, rather than the relationship (*AdInterest*).

Is there a nice, neat Collection method / pipeline I can use to combine the data and get access to the relationship fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-pluck) and [`flatten()`](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-flatten):

```php
$groups = AdInterestGroup::with('interests')->whereIn('id', [1, 2])->get();

$interests = $groups->pluck('interests')->flatten();

$foos = $interests->pluck('foo')->unique();
```

Comment: i dk if iam 100% correct but can't you do AdInterestGroup::with('interests:ad_id,interest_id,foo')->whereIn('id', [1, 2])->get(); so you don't use pluck ?